# Android Emulator Wear OS P - There's an internal problem with your device

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, wear-os

I've recently gotten a TicWatch Pro running Wear OS and am trying to make a new watch face for it but seem to be having issues with Android Studio.

When starting up the Android Emulator with Wear OS P, it starts up with an error message that says "There's an internal problem with your device. Contact your manufacturer for details."

Has anyone else had this issue and know how to fix it? I've tried uninstalling the SDKs and reinstalling them, deleting the emulators and creating new ones, and when trying a different SDK I get a compatibility error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mentioned in the release notes that 
"When the emulator performs a cold boot, the following error may be displayed: "There's an internal problem with your device. Contact the manufacturer for details." This does not affect functionality. Scroll down and click "OK" to begin testing your app."

That is the common issue with the wearOS but it does not effect the functionality

Check the release notes https://developer.android.com/wear/releases/